# SipServlet CRBT Implementation

Tags: java, mobicents-sip-servlets

Hi I want to implement CRBT using mobicents sipservlets.

for doing it i made a b2bua sipservlet that when it receives a call (first leg) it makes the second leg of call .
when it receives the 180 ringing from the second leg it makes another call to an ivr that configured to play a music. when it receives the 200 ok from ivr it sends a 183 session in progress with ivr 200 ok sdp content to first leg.
from this stage second leg keeps sending 180 but it seems that sipservlet dont receives messages even i pickup the second phone no 200 ok received. but if i reject the call it receives CANCEL message.
thanks for your suggestions.